# Compile-time evaluation of if-statements in Cython

Tags: cython

In Cython, is there a way to achieve compile time evaluation of a condition? For example something like

```
def func(bint value):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(1000000):
        # Some stuff is calculated
        if value:
            # Do something...
        else:
            # Do something else...
```

Is there a way to tell Cython to create two versions of the function, one for `value==True` and one for `value==False`? The evaluation of the if-statement in each loop iteration could have measurable performance costs otherwise.

Comment: Cython has `IF` and `DEF` to pick code at compile time (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276648/cython-precompiler-decision-making/47292793#47292793) but I don't think that's quite what you're after.

Comment: This is the kind of optimization that a good C compiler will probably do by itself anyway though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To @DavidW's comment, there is a decent chance the compiler recognizes and optimizes this by itself.  Comparable example on godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/g/JyK1Xe) - it seems the check is lifted with `-O3`, not with `-O2` on the particular GCC I'm using.

```
double func(bool value) {
    double accum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        if (value) {
            accum += 0.05;
        } else {
            accum += 0.10;
        }
    }
    return accum;
}
```

If you want to guarantee the check is lifted out of the loop, you obviously could manually lift out, though that presumably leads to code duplication.

If `value` is truly known at compile time, with `c++` you could use templates or `if constexpr` (c++17) to generate compile time specializations.

You would also have the option of using C macros to help manage the duplication.  IMO not worth the nastiness unless really performance critical, but it's there.