# Cython: What is similar to C include guard?

Tags: compilation, header, include, cython

I have a bunch of Cython files which cimport others in a complex dependency order. And the problem is, some cimport will make this error during compiling: `'Blahblah' redeclarared`

This issue is solved in C the very simple way with include guard:

```
#ifndef XXX_HH
#define XXX_HH
...
#endif
```

I can't find such include-guard similar feature in Cython, any work-around, generically? (not ad-hoc)

Comment: Have you tried [compile-time constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292793/1322972) ?

Comment: it says 'There is no direct equivalent of C #ifdef/#ifndef in Cython'

Comment: but for the second cimport, that DEF is still the same

Comment: [mre]. There is no equivalent to include guards. If you want a useful answer beyond that you probably need to show a simple example of what you're actually trying to solve

Comment: i can reorder the cimport to compile one pyx file, but that order again doesn't work when compiling the other pyx files

Comment: cython should add this feature, it's generically important

Comment: In C, it's arguably just a bad workaround for their dodgy textual inclusion model. So I'm not convinced that Cython should necessarily try to solve the problem the 1970s C way.

Comment: Why would you need it? In python it is not needed, why is it needed in cython in your opinion?

Comment: migration of a big project from python to cython, it's 'redeclare' import problem everywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to make a #ifndef-similar, but just to share the issue, it's rather weird. The problem was due to cimport-ing a forward declaration of a class itself.

File 1 `common.pxd`

```
cdef public struct myclass

cdef public cppclass output1:
    myclass* value

cdef public cppclass output2:
    float value

# Many more definitions...
```

File 2 `myclass.pxd`

```
# Due to common.pxd has so many definitions,
# this asterisk was used to cimport

# ERROR! IT INCLUDES THE FORWARD DECLARATION OF myclass
from common cimport * 

# OK HERE: INCLUDE 1 BY 1
from common cimport output1,output2,...

cdef public cppclass myclass:
    pass
```